# How to get from Malaga to Sierra Nevada via Motril?

Tags: buses, spain, andalusia

I try to find out how to get from Malaga to Trevelez or Lanjaron via Motril, not via Granada. I know there is a bus, since I have toke it 4 years ago but I cannot find any in the internet. I checked the Alsa.es side but I guess it was not an Alsa bus it took but some sort of school bus. Anyone who can help me finding a pdf with the schedules?

Comment: Using [Alsa](https://www.alsa.es/en) I was able to request Malaga to Lanjaron, and it returned a bus that takes just over 3.hours, and route you from Malaga, through Torre del Mar, Torrox, Narja, La Herradura, Almunecar, La Caleta de Salobre, Salobrena, Motril, Gorgoracha, Velez de Benaudalla, Orgiva, before arriving in Lanjaron.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rome2Rio is really good for this sort of thing.

Take a look here: https://www.rome2rio.com/s/M%C3%A1laga/Motril

You can then get a separate bus from Motril to either Trevelez or Lanjaron, whichever you actually prefer